# Regex for masking certain pattern in a String

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help me form a regex expression to replace the below pattern in java?

`"user=abc&password=abc123&token=xyz"`

Tried with `inputString.replaceAll(key + "=" + "([^\\s]+)", key + "=####&")`, but it results in
`"user=####&"`

However, I'm looking for replacing all occurrences where it matches the pattern `"key=value&"`. So final result should be `user=#####&password=#####&token=xyz`

Asterisk is not printed, so replacing with # for this post.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using a stream based approach, we can splitting the input on `&`, then checking each query string component for the keys of `user` or `password`.  In such a case, we then replace the values with a `#####` mask.  Finally, join back to a single query string at the end of the stream.

```java
String input = "user=abc&password=abc123&token=xyz";
String output = Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
    .map(x -> {
        String[] parts = x.split("=");
        if ("user".equals(parts[0]) || "password".equals(parts[0])) {
            parts[1] = "#####";
        }
        return String.join("=", parts);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

System.out.println(input);   // user=abc&password=abc123&token=xyz
System.out.println(output);  // user=#####&password=#####&token=xyz
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your input! I'm actually looking for a regix expression as there are existing patterns been masked using regix, and i want to add this pattern also.